# is it possible to build an application with external libraries of different ABI's

Tags: c++, linker-errors, abi

I have currently the problem that i need to build a application where it seems that the libraries are build with different c++ versions. 
When i build i got the `undefined reference std::__cxx11::basic_string` errors at one library and when i build with the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` i get undefined reference errors at `std::string` of the other library. 
They are both external libraries which i unfortunatly can't rebuild myself. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry, no. Different ABIs - no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible work-around I can think of is not very nice. Say you have libraries A and B with different ABI versions, vA and vB. Now, create a wrapper for library A which exposes an interface which is ABI-independent (plain `C`, i.e. all exposed functions should be declared with `extern "C"`). Then build this with ABI version vA (make sure to statically link needed vA libraries). Now you can build your application using ABI version vB linking with the wrapped library A (which should now be ABI-independent) and library B.

Of course, depending on the interface of library A, it may take some creativity to create a plain `C` interface, but it should be possible.

**Disclaimer**: I have not tried this myself, I recommend starting with a minimal test.

Comment: Make sure to hide all public symbols which might propagate from libraryA and libraryB to the corresponding wrapper libraries (i.e. force all symbols except your new C-API local). Otherwise you may face duplicate incompatible definition of some symbol coming from libraryA and libraryB.

Comment: so i need to put some efford in it to get it working. thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix different values of `GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` in a single file but you should be able to link files with different settings into a single library.

So if you are using the c++11 library in class `A` and the c++03 library in class `B` and class `A` and class `B` are in separate files and don't have `std::string` or `std::list` in their headers then it should be possible to link class `A` and class `B` into a single library.

Use of the pimpl pattern may be useful/required to achieve this.

The simplest approach is probably to produce a static library which wraps your c++03 library and is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` then you can compile the rest of your code as normal as long as you only interface with your c++03 library through the static library.